# Registering State Changes of Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, watch

If a state change occurs, I want to apply a function. But following watch provides me no proper information! All the time, I get `undefined`. What is my mistake?

**Root Controller (excerpt)**

```
$scope.$state = $state.
```

**Controller (excerpt)**

```
alert ($scope.$state.current.url);  // shows the current URL

$scope.$watch('$scope.$state.current.url', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("State Changes NewValue: ", newValue);
        console.log("State Changes OldValue: ", newValue);
    },true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have listner on the `$stateChangeSuccess` event which will get fired every time when state gets changed.

**Code**

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
   //code here which needs to be fire on each state transition.
   console.log(fromState); //will give the object of old state
   console.log(toState); //will give the object of current state
   console.log(toState.name); //current state name
})
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks ;)